# How do I change letter in string knowing it position in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace, genetic-algorithm

I have this problem, while writting genetic algorithm, when I try to simulate mutation process:
1. so I choose random `position = randint(0, len(genes)-1)`
where genes are in format "10101" and 1s and 0s are set randomly
2. I try to replace 1 or 0 with 0 or 1 to simulate mutation then I got many errors.

I tried this way:

```
position = randint(0, len(genes)-1)
if(genes[position]=="1"): 
    genes[position] = "0"
if(genes[position]=="0"): 
    genes[position] = "1"
```

That does not work. 
I tried also with:

```
if(genes[position_to_mutate]=="1"):
genes_new = ""
    if(position_to_mutate == 0):
        genes_new = "0" + genes[1:len(genes)]
        print "genes z zerowym nowym : ", genes
    if(position_to_mutate!=0):
        genes_new = genes[0:position_to_mutate] + "0" + genes[position_to_mutate+1:len(genes)]
    if(position_to_mutate==4):
        genes_new = genes[0:len(genes)-2] + "0"
```

So, how do I replace one sign with the other getting it by its position in the string?

Comment: How are you defining `genes`? What error is being thrown?

Comment: You cannot use assignment with strings as they are immutable so `genes[position]` etc..  is going to fail with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you need to reassign and you can do something like this:

```
genes = "101010101"
position = randint(0, len(genes)-1)
new_val = "1" if genes[position] == "0" else "0"
genes = genes[:position] + new_val + genes[position+1:]
```

Comment: I think you want `else "0"`

Answer (score 1):

strings in python are immutabe.

So you need to create new instance for modification.

Or you could use `list` for that purpose and after modifications convert it back to `str`.

```
>>> mystr = '1001'
>>> tmp = list(mystr)
>>> tmp[0] = '0'
>>> mystr = ''.join(tmp)
>>> mystr
'0001'
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented strings are immutable so you cannot use assignment, you could store the string in a [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray) and mutate that then just call str on the bytearray to get the new string back from the bytearray when you are finished mutating:

```
In [42]: s = "10101"

In [43]: b_s = bytearray(s)

In [44]: b_s[0] = "0"

In [45]: str(b_s)
Out[45]: '00101'

In [46]: b_s[0:2] = "11"

In [47]: str(b_s)
Out[47]: '11101'
```

It is going to be a lot more efficient if you make all the changes and then get your string back as opposed to continually creating new strings.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, strings are immutable. However, you can shorten your version using the niceties of the slice operator:

```
genes_new = genes[:p] + "0" + genes[p+1:]

# another way is to use this kind of generator expression
''.join(x[i] if i != p else '0' for i in xrange(len(x)))
```

Comment: it looks complicated but works fine, nice to know .join is useful!